# How to config Jackson date type in Spring4 by xml

Tags: json, spring

As u know,  will load some MessageConverters, one is
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter

But it only accepts date type "timestamp". I need to config it to accept date type likes "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". How to config for this requirement ?

Hope your help, Thx!

Comment: as u know, ... will load....      "mvc:annotation-driven" was lost,sorry